# Issue installing capybara-webkit gem, recursive error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capybara, capybara-webkit

```
Installing capybara-webkit (0.11.0) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find capybara-webkit-0.11.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

When I try to install the capybara-webkit gem, it says it cannot find the capybara-webkit gem. I already have qt4 installed:

```
$ sudo port list installed | grep qt4
qt4-mac                        @4.7.4          aqua/qt4-mac
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try installing qt using `brew` rather than `port`.

I have capybara-webkit installed on my mac right now (version 0.11.0 just as you were attempting to install) and it installed and works great.

However, I don't have port on my machine. I use `brew` to install most everything now.

So

```
brew install qt
```

could make a difference.

Here's a link to an installation script used by the team at Thoughtbot (the people who built and support capybara-webkit) -- you can see that it installs qt using brew as well:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/blob/master/mac

```
echo "Installing QT, used by Capybara Webkit for headless Javascript integration testing ..."
brew install qt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late on this one, but I've had a similar problem and figured out the problem was I had Macports **and** Homebrew installed.

So I uninstalled Macports:

`sudo port -fp uninstall installed`

Updated my Homebrew:

`brew update` (that took a while)

And then installed QT with only brew installed asking to build from source:

`brew install qt --build-from-source` (that took like 25 minutes to finish)

If you try `qmake -v` now, you'll probably get an error saying qmake is not in `/opt/local/bin`. This is because Homebrew installed QT in `/usr/local/bin`, and you have to add it to your PATH with the next command:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

In the end it took me like 3 hours to find the solution, but it worked like a charm.

I hope this helps other people having the same issue.